# When I want to add controller, data context class doesn't show in an ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application project, and I wanted to add a controller as "MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework".

Then I choose model class, but there is no options for data context class.

[image]

I tried to add  BlogContext (WebApplication1.Model) manually. but it doesn't work (unrecognized command or argument error).

Here is my `BlogContext` model:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
// Database işlemleri için
{
    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogContext():base("blogDb") // base blogVt diyince aynı veritabanını tekrar olusturuyor
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new BlogInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Blog> Bloglar { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Kategoriler { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the Data context class row, select the + (plus) sign

Here's the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) which has steps and screenshot... You may follow it.